# Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error occure when click on catalog product page in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

```
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error
<pre>#1 Magento\Ui\Model\Bookmark->getConfig() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Bookmark.php:81]
#2 Magento\Ui\Component\Bookmark->prepare() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:164]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:161]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:161]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:142]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:343]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#15 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Index.php:41]
#16 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#18 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#21 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#22 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#24 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be yours have garbage data at `ui_bookmark` database table.

Just truncate the table. It might be resolve.

Comment: thanks you issue resolved